# How to manage domains in Multi-site environment with Sitecore PaaS

Tags: multisite, paas

We are working on Sitecore 9.0.2 in PaaS with multi-site environment.
The domain for first site was created when we provisioned the environment using ARM templates.

Now question here is for second site, how to get unique domain for this site?

Site 1 --- Domain( `XXXX.cm.azurewebsites.net`)

Site 2 -(How to get Domain for this Site).

Answer (score 7):

In Azure Portal, on your CD's (or other instances) you can add custom domains.

[image]

Before doing so, you will need to add DNS records for those domains. You can CNAME them to the xxx-cd.azurewebsites.net site.

After that, it is just standard sitecore, where you need to add those domains in your sitecore configuration (sites node).

Comment: An extra note is that you can't add custom *.azurewebsites.net sites. You can only have the one default one which takes the name from the app service name.